# access Restful API data in jsreport templates

Tags: loopbackjs, dc.js, jsreport

I am using loopback  API to get data in [JSReport](http://jsreport.net/) 
I want to draw DC charts using templates and I need Recipe **html** of **jsreport**, so that I can embed it in my dashboard graphs. API for a jsreport can be different every time. i.e. at runtime we don't know the properties of over API, so how can I bind this API data with DC charts in jsreport template with '**html**'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing almost same problem and I was also using loopback.
The following link gives you solution for this problem
[link](http://jsreport.net/blog/using-input-data-in-html-page-inline-javascript)

Also you can ask your problems on Active google group too.
[Google group for jsreport](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!forum/jsreport)